# WLD Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Does anyone know of an example of a weakly Lindeloff determined (WLD) Banach space which does not contain c_0 and is not weak Asplund? I believe the example of a WLD, non-weak Asplund space by Argyros and Mercourakis contains c_0.

Comment: Try emailing Vaclav Zizler, Robb. I don't think he looks at MO.